# bundling install with gem

Tags: rubygems, bundle, gitlab

i try to bundle install but give me this error:

$bundle install
network connection error
https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/polyglot-0.3.3.gemspec.rz.

and try to :
$bundle install --local

could not found rake-10.1.0 in any of the source

Answer (score 0):

Update the bundler gem with:

`gem update bundler`

Seems to fix the problem for most.